# Text in center of Circle

Tags: java, swing

There is a circle (planet), drawn through fillOval(). I need to write the text (number) on the circle, so that it must be always aligned exactly in the center. There is a center of the circle and its radius.
I understand that I need to calculate the width and length of the text (tried by getStringBounds), but does not work correctly.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    for (Planet planet : planets) {
        g2d.setColor(planet.getColor());
        g2d.fillOval((int) planet.getX() - planet.getRadius(), (int) planet.getY() - planet.getRadius(),
        planet.getRadius() * 2, planet.getRadius() * 2);
        g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        String s = String.valueOf(250);
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        double textWidth = fm.getStringBounds(s, g).getWidth();
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(s, (int) ((int) planet.getX() - textWidth/2), ((int) planet.getY() + fm.getMaxAscent() / 2));}}
```

Comment: Please create and post a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool.

Comment: The basic idea seems ok (albeit you might want `(int) planet.getY() - fm.getMaxAscent() / 2)` ), so how does it not work ? How far off is the text ? What's the value of textWidth, and what is the position of the planet ?

Comment: `but does not work correctly.` - what does this mean? Is it always to the right/left/top/bottom. We are not mind readers. We can't guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `planet.getX()-planet.getRadius()` and `planet.getY() - planet.getRadius()` to calculate your centered point of the circle.

Then you have to add the Text you want to paint at the centered position, which is calculated

```
planet.getX() - planet.getRadius() - textWidth/2 //or centered point - textWidth/2
```

which is your x-coordinate and

```
planet.getY() - planet.getRadius() + fm.getMaxAscent() / 2 //or centered point + fm.getMaxAscent()/2
```

which will be the y-coordinate.

But you are using `planet.getX() - textWidth/2`

This origin point has to be the center of the circle, not `planet.getX()`

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've had to use both the ascent/descent values to calculate actual font height and it looks like you're only using ascent.  Something to consider: not all strings will have the same max ascent/descent for a given font, so while the string "Dojo" may appear to be properly vertically aligned, the strings "cujo" and "coco" might not.

Another suggestion: instead of calculating the half-width of your text and using that to offset your drawing starting position, why not just center justify the text?